# How come Loki does not have the window snap feature?

Tags: release-loki, pantheon-files, desktop

I noticed something weird, I can snap one window but not another. Is this done purposely or is this a bug? So meaning that I can't snap two windows side by side.

Comment: I can second that it is there, but for some reason there are no snapping borders, which is confusing. The no snapping border outlines may be a bug. Does anyone know if the absence of snapping outlines is a bug or intentional?

Answer (score 4):

What do you mean? Window snapping is definitely there in Loki (source: I'm using it right now on Chrome, snapped to full-screen).

Note that some windows have fixed, forced sizes, and therefore cannot be altered by the window manager. Thus these devices will not snap into place.

Comment: I've noticed this behavior in Avocode. This app has a minimum window size, and snapping the window would have put the window below the minimum size, so snapping doesn't work with this app.